# App Engine: How can I give an image response using self.response.out using the webapp2 framework?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to send an image as a response, but I would like to do some work before that, so I basically can't just use the static .yaml route. Here is the code:

```
trackingModel = TrackingModel(uuid = key, ip_address=self.request.remote_addr)
        logging.info("Remote IP address: %s and current user is: %s", self.request.remote_addr, self.get_user_from_session())
        trackingModel.put()
        #self.response.write(trackingModel.time)
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mail.google.com')
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        self.response.headers['Content-Length'] = '0'
        self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store'
        self.response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
```

How can I return a 1px image from the same /static directory that returns my other static js and css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the work, then redirect to location of the image.

```
# do work
self.redirect('/static/image.gif')
```

Alternatively, set the `Content-Type` to the mime type matching the image, then open the image as a file and write it. A bit more work on the program side, but it saves the extra round trip that the redirect introduced.

Comment: I also need to add some headers to the response:

Comment: I also need to add some headers to the response:


self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mail.google.com')
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        self.response.headers['Content-Length'] = '0'
        self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store'
        self.response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'


The issue is that App Engine doesn't seem to be allowing me to set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and Content-Length. Need it to control caching behavior.

Comment: Why are you trying to set `Content-Length` to 0?

Comment: So this is a 1px by 1px image that I attach to emails. From the website:
"""
EDIT: Rene has done further testing and has found the crucial element is ” ‘Content-length’ (=0) than of ‘content-type’. Returning nothing in combination with a HTTP 200 OK forces Gmail to grab the tracking code over and over again.”
"""
http://emailexpert.org/gmail-tracking-changes-the-fix-what-you-need-to-know/